# Ошибка ERROR: Failed to resolve, при добавлении новой зависимости в build.gradle

Tags: java, android-studio

Хотел добавить BottomNavigationView для этого подключил зависимость `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'`, но ни к чему хорошему это не привело, как подключить её без ошибок? 
Вот весь код

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.navigatiobarexmpl"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Comment: Нет такой библиотеки. Есть `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

Comment: Спасибо, просто во всех видеоуроках и статьях используют эту

Answer (score 1):

`BottomNavigationView` находится внутри `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`, `'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'` - не существует :)

[google maven repo](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html)

[image: google maven repo]